# How to overload or monkeypatch Request.remote_ip or Request.ip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, monkeypatching

I need to patch or overload Request.remote_ip (or would Request.ip be better as I see some mentioning that this should be used instead of remote_ip) such that it acts as normal, but if `CF-Connecting-IP` is in the header, it will return this IP address rather than the one it normally detects.

**How do I set up this patch appropriately in terms of the class and method definition?**

Essentially I'm trying to simply return the following for each request:

```
headers["CF-Connecting-IP"] || remote_ip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't monkey patch a method on request. Instead, I'd make a helper method in your application controller that does exactly what you just posted:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...

  def connecting_ip
    headers["CF-Connecting-IP"] || request.remote_ip
  end
end
```

And just use connecting_ip wherever this is important.

Comment: Actually had to put it in the controller as I couldn't figure out how to use the application_helper without putting in a `helper :all` or such.  Is that kosher? Or what should I do when `connecting_ip` needs to be visible throughout the app and perhaps in rake tasks?